# Which PDF of X leads to a Gumbel distribution of the finite-size average of X?

Tags: mean, density-function, iid, gumbel-distribution

Consider the statistic "average of $N$ idd random variables $X_i$",

$$S_N = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i
$$
Consider also that, by a numerical experiment, it is observed that the distribution of $S_N$, $P(S_N)$, is a [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) (e.g. p-value does not reject the null hypothesis that it is).

Which $P(X_i) = P(X)$ can explain these observations?

More quantitatively, what can lead to a Gumbel distribution of the (finite-size) mean of a random variable? If no such process exists for iid, what correlation can explain these observations?

(I am aware of the occurrence of the Gumbel distribution on block maxima, but this seems to be unrelated to this problem.)

EDIT:

In my actual problem, I currently do not have access to the time series of $X_i$, so I can't tell you whether they are correlated, but most likely they are correlated. Moreover, $X_i \in [0, 1]$. The iid assumption was a first approach to the problem, to see if there was a simple distribution of $X_i$ that could explain the Gumbel distribution of the mean.

Comment: Since for large $N$ the Central Limit Theorem implies $S_N$ will have an approximately Normal distribution, and no Gumbel distribution is Normal, it is important to know the value of $N$. In particular, the answer when $N=1$ is a Gumbel distribution.  Could you tell us what your $N$ is and what the estimated Gumbel parameters might be?

Comment: The Gumbel distribution [is infinitely divisible](https://goo.gl/QZxwEZ), so there exists such a representation.

Comment: @Xi'an (It's ok to ignore the exponential in the CF because that's easily handled.)  For $n\gt 1$ the root of the Gamma function is not a Gamma function, so you have just shown that the distribution of $X$ is *not* Gumbel.  I don't recognize this CF, nor can I invert it.

Comment: @whuber: The central limit theorem does not apply when $X_i$ doesn't have its first two moments, which would narrow this down.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: Are you absolutely positive your $X_i$ are iid? Could there be some correlation, or more precisely could the mean and variance of $X_i$ be changing with $i$?

Comment: @Alex Gumbel distributions have finite variances.  That's why I made no effort to qualify the CLT.

Comment: Thanks Alex R, whuber, and Xi'an. I have no reason to believe that $X_i$ are uncorrelated. I was trying to first see whether assuming they are not could have a simple explanation. I do not have direct access to $X_i$ at the moment to tell whether the autocorrelation function of $X_i$. in my problem $X_i \in [0,1]$ (I updated the question with this information). Yeah, Alex, $X_i$ is also not necessarily stationary in my problem.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: Could you actually just post some histograms along with fits? Also if possible try fitting a normal and Poisson distribution for comparison.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: Maybe I'm not completely understanding your question though, because if $X_i$ have finite mean, then your $S_N$ converges almost surely to the mean. However it sounds like you're interested in fluctuations around the mean, i.e. something akin to CLT?

Comment: @AlexR., my question is what can explain a Gumbel distribution of the mean. Yes, I am interested on the tails. :) My hypothesis are either a PDF of $X_i$ or some known correlation of $X_i$, but it could be neither. I have this data, and I got interested on what could explain it.

Comment: Also, where does the data for $X_i$ come from (if it's not a secret)?

Comment: @whuber: The gumbel distribution is in fact infinitely divisible, although this is far from obvious. Recall that infinite divisibility does not require the "divising" distributions to be the same as the original distribution. Infinite divisibility follows from the observation that for $X_i$ exponentially distributed and iid,

$\max\{X_1,\cdots,X_n\}=^d \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i}{i},$

Where the equality is in distribution. Infinite divisibility follows from the fact that the exponential is infinitely divisible.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: Could you do the following experiment? Could you check if your $X_i$ have exponential distributions with a mean that varies with $i$?

Comment: @Alex Yes, all that is apparent.  But I view it as being beside the point, because of the obviously *approximate* nature of this question.  It reminds me rather of a "principle" of geostatistics called the "conservation of lognormality."  It states that (within certain limits) the linear combinations of (correlated) lognormal variables that are used in many Kriging applications are themselves lognormal--even though theoretically they cannot be.  The point is that it's a good enough approximation to justify treating them as lognormal anyway.

Comment: @Xi'an: Wouldn't you need to first prove that this is a characteristic function? I.E. use Polya's theorem, where the only nontrivial step is to show it's convex for $t>0$? Afterall, if $\phi(t)$ is a characteristic function, this does not imply $\phi(nt)^{1/n}$ is a characteristic function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gumbel distribution has as pdf

$$f(x)=\exp\{-x-e^{-x}\}$$

which corresponds to the transform 
$$X=-\log(Y)\qquad Y\sim\mathcal{E}(1)$$
where $\mathcal{E}(\lambda)$ is the exponential distribution. The moment generating function is

$$\Phi(t)=\mathbb{E}[\exp\{tX\}]=\Gamma(1-t)$$

by a simple change of variable into $Y$. As detailed in [this book](http://tinyurl.com/h6xqrup) (p.443), albeit with a slightly different definition of the Gumbel, the Gamma function satisfies the property that

$$\Gamma(1-t)=e^{-\gamma t}\prod_{i=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{t}{i}\right)^{-1}e^{-t/i}$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. The central term in the product is the moment generating function of an exponential variate $E_i$ with scale $1/i$. Therefore a Gumbel variable can be written as
$$X=\lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^m\{E_i-i^{-1}\}-\gamma=\lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^m E_i-\log(m)$$
It then follows from the infinite decomposability of the exponential distribution that each $E_i$ can be written as $E_i=\sum_{j=1}^n V_{ij}/n$, where the $V_{ij}$'s are Gamma $\mathcal{G}(1/n,n/i)$, hence that
$$X=\lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^m \left[ \sum_{j=1}^n \{V_{ij}/n-\log(m)/n\}\right]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \left[\lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^m \{V_{ij} - \log(m)\}\right]$$
is indeed infinitely divisible. (Thanks to Gérard Letac for his help.)

Comment: I have made some corrections, but I still don't get the last step. I.e. How come that $\log(m)/n$ appears in the last equation? Replacing $E_i$ on the equation for X should not modify the term $\log(m)$.

Comment: What about $\log(m)=\sum_{i=1}^n\log(m)/n$?

Answer (score 2):

To complement Xi'an's answer, here is a situation where one encounters *the Gumbel distribution as a sum of a random variable* (not a mean).

Let independent random variables $X_j=-\log(V_j)$, where  $V_j\sim\mbox{beta}(j\sigma,1-\sigma)$, $j\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $\sigma\in(0,1)$. Then the sum of $X_j$s, after proper centering, behaves very similarly to a Gumbel distribution, see for instance the plot here: [Central limit theorem for independent random variables, with a Gumbel limit](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164288/central-limit-theorem-for-independent-random-variables-with-a-gumbel-limit).